How can I make multiple loaded images get stacked horizontally(left to right)?
Description
Currently, if the user pastes images multiple times to the chat input using the 'ctrl' and 'v' keys, they get stacked vertically. The chat input is right above the 'run' button. Above the chat input is where the loaded images are displayed.
Expected Behavior
Make the loaded multiple images get stacked horizontally(left to right) if the user pastes images multiple times to the chat input.
Current Behavior
Currently, loaded multiple images get stacked vertically.

HTML, CSS, JS


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const textInput = document.getElementById('textInput');
  const imageContainer = document.getElementById('imageContainer');
  const runButton = document.getElementById('runButton');

  textInput.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
      const items = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).items;
      for (const item of items) {
          if (item.type.indexOf('image') !== -1) {
              const file = item.getAsFile();
              const reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = (event) => {
                  displayImage(event.target.result);
              };
              reader.readAsDataURL(file);
              event.preventDefault();
          }
      }
  });

  function displayImage(src) {
      const imgContainer = document.createElement('div');
      imgContainer.classList.add('img-preview-container');
      
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = src;
      img.classList.add('img-preview');
      
      const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
      removeButton.classList.add('remove-button');
      removeButton.textContent = '✖';
      removeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
          imgContainer.remove();
      });

      imgContainer.appendChild(img);
      imgContainer.appendChild(removeButton);
      imageContainer.appendChild(imgContainer);
  }

  runButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('Run button clicked');
  });
});
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #181818;
}

.chat-container {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 800px;
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    outline: 2px solid black; /* Added outline */
}

.input-container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.image-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 5px;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.run-button {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #3b82f6;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.run-button:hover {
    background-color: #2563eb;
}

.img-preview-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.img-preview {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.remove-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Chat Input with Image Paste</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="chat-container">
      <div class="image-container" id="imageContainer"></div>
      <div
        class="input-container"
        contenteditable="true"
        id="textInput"
        placeholder="Type something"
      ></div>
      <button class="run-button" id="runButton">Run</button>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>




Stacks horizontally for me in Chrome and FF

Could you please check my post again? I've updated it by adding the image of how it looks like when I run the code snippet. I have no idea why the images are getting stacked vertically for me.

Try adding the flex-direction:row attribute to your body tag and see if that changes anything

The issue is your image divs are full 100% width by default, even though they're inline-block elements. You need to set the width of each one.
In my example, I did that by setting the width of each one dynamically based on how many images there are: ${100/all_images.length-10}%.
I subtracted 10 additional pixels to account for padding and margin for this example instead of trying to calculate that dynamically.
const all_images = imageContainer.querySelectorAll('.img-preview-container');
all_images.forEach(img=>img.style.width=`${100/all_images.length-10}%`);



document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const textInput = document.getElementById('textInput');
  const imageContainer = document.getElementById('imageContainer');
  const runButton = document.getElementById('runButton');

  textInput.addEventListener('paste', (event) => {
      const items = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData).items;
      for (const item of items) {
          if (item.type.indexOf('image') !== -1) {
              const file = item.getAsFile();
              const reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = (event) => {
                  displayImage(event.target.result);
              };
              reader.readAsDataURL(file);
              event.preventDefault();
          }
      }
  });

  function displayImage(src) {
      const imgContainer = document.createElement('div');
      imgContainer.classList.add('img-preview-container');
      
      const img = document.createElement('img');
      img.src = src;
      img.classList.add('img-preview');
      
      const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
      removeButton.classList.add('remove-button');
      removeButton.textContent = '✖';
      removeButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
          imgContainer.remove();
      });

      imgContainer.appendChild(img);
      imgContainer.appendChild(removeButton);
      imageContainer.appendChild(imgContainer);
      
      const all_images = imageContainer.querySelectorAll('.img-preview-container');
      all_images.forEach(img=>img.style.width=`${100/all_images.length-10}%`);
  }

  runButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      console.log('Run button clicked');
  });
});
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #181818;
}

.chat-container {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 800px;
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    outline: 2px solid black; /* Added outline */
}

.input-container {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.image-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    border: 1px solid #444;
    border-radius: 5px;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.run-button {
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #3b82f6;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.run-button:hover {
    background-color: #2563eb;
}

.img-preview-container {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.img-preview {
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.remove-button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    background-color: #ff4d4d;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Chat Input with Image Paste</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="chat-container">
      <div class="image-container" id="imageContainer"></div>
      <div
        class="input-container"
        contenteditable="true"
        id="textInput"
        placeholder="Type something"
      ></div>
      <button class="run-button" id="runButton">Run</button>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>




Seems like if I paste images multiple times, the size of each loaded image gets smaller. I wonder if I want to maintain the same size of the loaded images regardless of the number of images I pasted, I should just tinker with the ${100/all_images.length-10}% part?
